# C++ compile error messages not showing properly in PuTTY

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, putty

If I compile a C++ program with errors in Linux connected through PuTTY, I see error messages like:

```
g++ a.cpp
a.cpp: In function âint main()â:
a.cpp:38: error: expected primary-expression before â)â token
a.cpp:38: error: âwaitpidâ was not declared in this scope
```

Any idea about why the character `â` is coming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure command `locale` returns the same encoding which set in PuTTY configuration *Translation->Received data assumed to be in which character set*.

Answer (score 2):

Set the PuTTY charset to UTF-8 in the options.